# Running Aria2 commands from a bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, aria2

I'm currently using Aria2, a downloading software that you use via cmd, to download a list of content.
It requires you to CD to the directory where you have a parameter file that outlines your downloads (multiple url/file names).

I was wondering how I would go about to create a batch file that will execute the Aria command to download to each folder one-by-one

For example the batch file would work along these lines

```
CD c:/folder1
aria2 command1
::after aria2 command1 is done and the downloads have completed
CD c:/folder2
aria2 command2
::after aria2 command2 is done and the downloads have completed
```

And so forth

At the moment I have to open up cmd or powershell and manually input the CD destination and aria2 command, wait  until it's done, and input the next CD and aria2 command. If I try running the .bat with commands like above, aria2 doesn't run properly, and provides me the following error:
[httpskipresponsecomand.cc:219] errorcode=3 resource not found

I'm hoping to create a bat file with a bunch of aria2 commands that'll run consecutively so I don't need to be present to execute the commands, and it'll carry on without me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You already wrote your program. Open Notepad and put each command on separate line and save it as `blablabla.cmd` (choose in `Save as type`: All files `*.*`)

Comment: first of all, for some reason my .bat files weren't in ANSI, and that seem to be the issue. Another problem arose, where the aria commands wouldn't work when the bat/cmd file was executed. But they work fine when just manually executed in cmd prompt or powershell... I get this error: [httpskipresponsecomand.cc:219] errorcode=3 resource not found

Comment: You don't have to use CD command. Aria2c has a `-d` option to mention download directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Biswapriyo, but the same errors show up regardless of using CD or using -d within the aria command: [httpskipresponsecomand.cc:219] errorcode=3 resource not found

Comment: I'm not certain of the answer, but I see that people are reading the title and answering the title.  I edited the title to make the problem clear.  I suggest shortening the question to make it more readable.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks again for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the same error shows up.  here is an example of the aria command, which works when executed separately (one-by-one) in cmd or powershell, but gives the error above when run via .bat/.cmd file:
aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here -j 5 --check-certificate=false http://site.address.here.com/videofiles/video_[1-200].ts

Comment: @Biswapriyo yes. I can download the files via browser. If I run a bat file with
aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here1 -j 5 --check-certificate=false site.address.here.com/videofiles/video1_[1-200].ts in the 1st line and
aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here2 -j 5 --check-certificate=false site.address.here.com/videofiles/video2_[1-200].ts in the 2nd line, that error shows up. However, if I run each command separately (manually), for example, copy&paste the 1st command, wait till it finishes, and copy&paste the 2nd one, no error and downloads are fine.

Comment: Then try aria2c with a `For /L` loop.

Comment: Can't seem to get aria2 to work properly with For /L loop. Since I'm not very knowledgeable on the matter, my attempts might be incorrect. Trying to use FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,200) DO aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here1 -j 5 --check-certificate=false site.address.here.com/videofiles/video1_%%G.ts